# Vertical RecyclerView nested inside vertical RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have spent hours/days reading around this subject but still can't find something that works.  I'm trying to put a fixed-height vertically-scrolling `RecyclerView` in the row of another vertically-scrolling `RecyclerView`.

Much of the advice is along the lines of "it's a crime to put a vertically-scrolling `RecyclerView` inside another vertically-scrolling `RecyclerView`"... but I can't figure out why this is so bad.

In fact, the behavior would be almost exactly the same as many pages on StackOverflow (e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45876645)... *and indeed this very question*, at least when viewed on a mobile device), where the code sections are of a fixed (or max) height, and scroll vertically, and are contained within a page that itself scrolls vertically.  What happens is that when the focus is on the code section, scrolling happens within that section, and when it reaches the upper/lower end of the scroll range of the section, then scrolling happens within the outer page.  It's quite natural, not evil.

This is my recycler_view_row_outer.xml (a row within the outer `RecyclerView`):

```
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    style="@style/MyCardView"
    app:cardElevation="4dp"
    app:strokeColor="?attr/myCardBorderColor"
    app:strokeWidth="0.7dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="8dp" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            style="@style/MyTextView.Section"
            android:id="@+id/list_title" />

        <LinearLayout
            style="@style/MyLinearLayoutContainer"
            android:id="@+id/list_container"
            android:layout_below="@+id/list_title" >
        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

And this is my `recycler_view_row_inner.xml` (a row within the inner `RecyclerView`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/my_constraint_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/list_container" >

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view_inner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/my_constraint_layout"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/my_constraint_layout"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_max="750dp"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_min="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/my_constraint_layout"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/my_constraint_layout" >
    </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

With the above inner layout, I've tried to follow the approach set out in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54474267), to create an inner `RecyclerView` having a fixed/max height... but it isn't working.

I inflate the inner layout (added to `list_container`/`containerView` in the outer layout) and set up my inner `recyclerView` as follows:

```
View inflatedView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.recycler_view_row_inner, containerView, false);
RecyclerView recyclerView = inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_inner);
// set adapter, row data, etc
```

But all this does is create a fixed-height inner row that *does not scroll* within the outer row... overflow content of the inner row is just cut off and I can't reach the lower part of it because it just scrolls the outer row.

Any idea how to make this work?

Comment: Have you evaluated a solution using nested scroll view with the recycler views? That ideally should take care of nested scrolling behaviour out of the box.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Approach No.1: Using two nested RecyclerViews

[**Github sample**](https://github.com/M7mdZain/VerticalNestedRecyclerView)

**Pros:**

- Views are recycled (i.e. Good performance)
- Semi-Seamless scrolling (after update 3 & 4)

**Cons:**

- The programmatically propagated scroll during the transition from the inner to the outer scroll when the inner far end  item is reached is not that smooth/natural like the gesture.
- Complex code.

Well, I won't address the performance issues of vertically nested `RecyclerViews`; But notice that:

- The inner `RecyclerView` probably loses the ability of recycling views; because the shown rows of the outer recyclerView should load their items entirely. (Thankfully it's not a right assumption as per the below UPDATE 1)
- I declared a single adapter instance in the `ViewHolder` not in the `onBindViewHolder` to have a better performance by not creating a new adapter instance for the inner `RecyclerView` each time views are recycled.

The demo app represents the months of the year as the outer `RecyclerView`, and the day numbers of each month as inner `RecyclerView`.

The outer `RecyclerView` registers `OnScrollListener` that each time it's scrolled, we do this check on the inner RV:

- If outer scrolling up: check if the inner first item is shown.
- If outer scrolling down: check if the inner last item is shown.

```
    outerRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {

        @Override
        public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            if (dy > 0) //scrolled to BOTTOM
                outerAdapter.isOuterScrollingDown(true, dy);
            else if (dy < 0) //scrolled to TOP
                outerAdapter.isOuterScrollingDown(false, dy);
        }
    });
```

In the outer adapter:

```
    public void isOuterScrollingDown(boolean scrollDown, int value) {
        if (scrollDown) {
            boolean isLastItemShown = currentLastItem == mMonths.get(currentPosition).dayCount;
            if (!isLastItemShown) onScrollListener.onScroll(-value);
            enableOuterScroll(isLastItemShown);

        } else {
            boolean isFirstItemShown = currentFirstItem == 1;
            if (!isFirstItemShown) onScrollListener.onScroll(-value);
            enableOuterScroll(isFirstItemShown);
        }
        if (currentRV != null)
            currentRV.smoothScrollBy(0, 10 * value);
    }
```

If the relevant item is not shown, then we decide to disable the outer RV scrolling. This is handled by a listener with a callback that accepts a boolean passed to a customized `LinearLayoutManager` class to the outer RV.

Likewise in order to re-enable scrolling of the outer RV: the inner `RecyclerView` registers `OnScrollListener` to check if the inner first/last item is shown.

```
innerRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {

    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {

        if (!recyclerView.canScrollVertically(1) // Is it not possible to scroll more to bottom (i.e. Last item shown)
                && newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
            enableOuterScroll(true);

        } else if (!recyclerView.canScrollVertically(-1) // Is it possible to scroll more to top (i.e. First item shown)
                && newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
            enableOuterScroll(true);
        }
    }
});
```

Still, there are glitches because disabling/enabling scrolling; we can't pass the scroll order to the other RV, until the next scroll. This is manipulated slightly by reversing the initial outer RV scroll value; and using an arbitrary scroll value to the inner with `currentRV.smoothScrollBy(0, 10 * initialScroll)`. I wish if someone can suggest any other alternative to this.

**UPDATE 1**

> - The inner `RecyclerView` probably lose the ability of recycling views; because the shown rows of the outer recyclerView should load their items entirely.

Thankfully it's not the right assumption and the views are recycled by tracking the recycled list of items in the inner adapter using a `List` that hold the currently loaded items:

By assuming some month has a 1000 days "Feb as it's always oppressed :)", and scrolling up/down to notice the loaded list and make sure that [`onViewRecycled()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter#onViewRecycled(VH)) get called.

```
public class InnerRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<InnerRecyclerAdapter.InnerViewHolder> {

    private final ArrayList<Integer> currentLoadedPositions = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull InnerViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.tvDay.setText(String.valueOf(position + 1));
        currentLoadedPositions.add(position);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onViewRecycled: " + days + " " + currentLoadedPositions);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewRecycled(@NonNull InnerViewHolder holder) {
        super.onViewRecycled(holder);
        currentLoadedPositions.remove(Integer.valueOf(holder.getAdapterPosition()));
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onViewRecycled: " + days + " " + currentLoadedPositions);
    }
    
    // Rest of code is trimmed

}
```

Logs:

```
onViewRecycled: 1000 [0]
onViewRecycled: 1000 [0, 1]
onViewRecycled: 1000 [0, 1, 2]
onViewRecycled: 1000 [0, 1, 2, 3]
onViewRecycled: 1000 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
onViewRecycled: 1000 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
onViewRecycled: 1000 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
onViewRecycled: 1000 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
onViewRecycled: 1000 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
onViewRecycled: 1000 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
onViewRecycled: 1000 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
onViewRecycled: 1000 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
onViewRecycled: 1000 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
onViewRecycled: 1000 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
onViewRecycled: 1000 [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
onViewRecycled: 1000 [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
onViewRecycled: 1000 [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
onViewRecycled: 1000 [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
onViewRecycled: 1000 [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
onViewRecycled: 1000 [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
onViewRecycled: 1000 [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
onViewRecycled: 1000 [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]
onViewRecycled: 1000 [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]
onViewRecycled: 1000 [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17]
onViewRecycled: 1000 [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17]
onViewRecycled: 1000 [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]
onViewRecycled: 1000 [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]
onViewRecycled: 1000 [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
onViewRecycled: 1000 [9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
onViewRecycled: 1000 [9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
onViewRecycled: 1000 [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
onViewRecycled: 1000 [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21]
onViewRecycled: 1000 [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21]
onViewRecycled: 1000 [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22]
onViewRecycled: 1000 [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22]
onViewRecycled: 1000 [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23]
onViewRecycled: 1000 [13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23]
onViewRecycled: 1000 [13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24]
onViewRecycled: 1000 [14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24]
onViewRecycled: 1000 [14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25]
```

**UPDATE 2**

> Still there are glitches because disabling/enabling scrolling; we can't pass the scroll order to the other RV, until the next scroll. This is manipulated slightly by reversing the initial outer RV scroll value; and using an arbitrary scroll value to the inner with `currentRV.smoothScrollBy(0, 10 * initialScroll)`. I wish if someone can suggest any other alternative to this.

- Using a greater arbitrary value (like 30) makes the grammatical scroll looks smoother >> `currentRV.smoothScrollBy(0, 30 * initialScroll)`
- And scrolling the outer scroll without reversing the scroll, makes it also looks more natural in the same direction of the scroll:

```
if (scrollDown) {
    boolean isLastItemShown = currentLastItem == mMonths.get(currentPosition).dayCount;
    if (!isLastItemShown) onScrollListener.onScroll(value);
    enableOuterScroll(isLastItemShown);

} else {
    boolean isFirstItemShown = currentFirstItem == 1;
    if (!isFirstItemShown) onScrollListener.onScroll(value);
    enableOuterScroll(isFirstItemShown);
}
```

**UPDATE 3**

Issue: glitches during the transition from the outer to inner `RecyclerView` because the `onScroll()` of the outer gets called before deciding whether we can scroll the inner or not.

By using `OnTouchListener` to the outer RecyclerView and overriding `onTouch()` and return `true` to consume the event (so that `onScrolled()` won't get called) until we decide that the inner can take the scroll over.

```
private float oldY = -1f;
outerRecyclerView.setOnTouchListener((v, event) -> {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onTouch: ");
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            oldY = -1;
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            float newY = event.getRawY();
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onTouch: MOVE " + (oldY - newY));

            if (oldY == -1f) {
                oldY = newY;
                return true; // avoid further listeners (i.e. addOnScrollListener)

            } else if (oldY < newY) { // increases means scroll UP
                outerAdapter.isOuterScrollingDown(false, (int) (oldY - newY));
                oldY = newY;

            } else if (oldY > newY) { // decreases means scroll DOWN
                outerAdapter.isOuterScrollingDown(true, (int) (oldY - newY));
                oldY = newY;
            }
            break;
    }
    return false;
});
```

**UPDATE 4**

- Enabling the scroll transition from the inner to outer `RecyclerView` whenever the inner RV scrolled to its top or bottom edge so that it continues scrolling to the outer RV by a proportional speed.

The scroll speed is inspired by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7895504/how-to-get-the-scroll-speed-on-a-listview). By applying the first/last item checks in the touched inner RV's `OnTouchListener` & `OnScrollListener` , and resetting stuff in a brand new touch event i.e. in `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN`

- Disable over-scroll mode in both inner & outer `RecyclerView`s

Preview:

[image]

## Approach No.2: Wrapping outer RecyclerView in NestedScrollView

[Github sample](https://github.com/M7mdZain/NestedVerticalRecyclerViewByNestedScrollView)

The main issue of the nested scrolling of a `RecyclerView` is that it doesn't implement [NestedScrollingParent3](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/view/NestedScrollingParent3) interface which is implemented by `NestedScrollView`; So `RecyclerView` can't handle nested scrolling of child views. So, trying to compensate that with a `NestedScrollView` by wrapping the outer `RecyclerView` within a `NestedScrollView`, and disable the scrolling of the outer `RecyclerView`

**Pros:**

- Simple code (You don't have to manipulate inner/outer scrolling at all)
- No glitch
- Seamless scrolling

**Cons:**

- Low performance as views of the outer `RecyclerView` are not recycled and so that they have to be all loaded before showing up on the screen.

Reason: Due to the nature of the `NestedScrollView` >> Check [(1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37590651/recyclerview-does-not-recycling-views-when-use-it-inside-nestedscrollview), [(2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42782786/how-to-make-recyclerview-do-recycling-inside-nestedscrollview) questions that discussed the recycling issues:

## Approach No.3: Using ViewPager2 as the outer RecyclerView

[**Github sample**](https://github.com/M7mdZain/SimpleViewPager2RecyclerViewAdapter)

Using a `ViewPager2` that functions internally using a `RecyclerView` solves the problem of recycling views, but only one page (one outer row) can present at a time.

**Pros:**

- No glitches & Seamless scrolling upon using [`NestedScrollableHost`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57587618/viewpager2-with-horizontal-scrollview-inside#63395308)
- Views are recycled as there is an internal `RecyclerView` in `ViewPager2`

**Cons:**

- Showing only a single item per page

So we probably tackle this by researching either:

- How to show Multiple views per page
- How to wrap_content a page

Comment: This looks very interesting indeed.  I'll check out the sample.  But one thing I notice is the first caveat: `"The inner RecyclerView probably lose the ability of recycling views; because the shown rows of the outer recyclerView should load their items entirely"`.  This would be a big negative for me, because some of these inner RVs have a *lot* of rows (this is part of the reason I'm migrating from plain ViewGroup to RV) so I would really need to avoid adding *all* items at once.  Is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: @drmrbrewer Thankfully it's was not a right assumption.. Please have a look at UPDATE section in the answer

Comment: I tried the sample (after your UPDATE 2 changes).  It's pretty close.  It does still feel a little glitchy, in that the outer RV sometimes scrolls a tiny bit even when scrolling the inner RV (not at either extreme).  Also, it doesn't seem possible to scroll the outer RV when actually touching/scrolling on the month names... this would be particularly important when these "sections" are closed (inner RV hidden) so that it's mainly *only* the outer RV (month rows) showing.  And I am surprised that it takes so much effort to get close to achieving what *should* IMHO happen automatically.

Comment: @drmrbrewer Please have a look at `UPDATE 3`  in the first approach, and at the second and third approaches

Comment: thank you.  Your answer is a great help to me and I am sure others will find it useful too.  For me, approach 2 is the most appealing, because of its relative simplicity (just wrapping the RV inside a NSV).  In my case the outer RV is relatively short and very simple (effectively just section titles, very similar to your month names, but more of them), so it's not a great hardship to have to lay out all rows from the start (if it allows me to retain the other benefits of the RV model).

Comment: @drmrbrewer Thanks for following along, and glad to hear that approach 2 is much close to your thought; now just updated approach 1 *(UPDATE 4)*, and slightly adjusted the cons. Thanks to have a look.

Answer (score 9):

Here is an approach that retrofits *RecyclerView* with the [NestedScrollingParent3](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/view/NestedScrollingParent3) interface.  The *NestedRecyclerView* class is used as the outer *RecyclerView* and a stock *RecyclerView* is used as an inner item view.

The following code is based upon code from *Widgetlabs* [here](https://github.com/Widgetlabs/expedition-nestedscrollview) which is licensed under the MIT License. The code presented below has been heavily modified from the original.

**Operation**
When the outer *RecyclerView* is touched, it can be scrolled up and down as expected and the inner *RecyclerView* is dragged along.

When the inner *RecyclerView* is touched, it can be scrolled up and down without effecting the outer *RecyclerView*. When the inner *RecyclerView* reaches it fullest extent either down or up, the outer *RecyclerView* starts to scroll. Once the outer *RecyclerView* starts to scroll, it has captured the gesture and will not release it until another "down" event. This is different from how *RecyclerView* behaves within a [NestedScrollView](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/widget/NestedScrollView) where the outer *RecyclerView* scrolls but inner *RecyclerView* will resume consuming the scroll gesture when the scroll direction changes.  In essence, the inner *RecyclerView* never relinquishes control while here it does.

The following video demonstrates the operation of *NestedRecyclerView*. In the video, the inner *RecyclerView* has a white border and orange and red rows. Everthing else is the outer *RecyclerView*.

[image]

**NestedRecyclerView**

```
open class NestedRecyclerView @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : RecyclerView(context, attrs, defStyleAttr), NestedScrollingParent3 {

    private var nestedScrollTarget: View? = null
    private var nestedScrollTargetWasUnableToScroll = false
    private val parentHelper by lazy { NestedScrollingParentHelper(this) }

    override fun dispatchTouchEvent(ev: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        // Nothing special if no child scrolling target.
        if (nestedScrollTarget == null) return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev)

        // Inhibit the execution of our onInterceptTouchEvent for now...
        requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true)
        // ... but do all other processing.
        var handled = super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev)

        // If the first dispatch yielded an unhandled event or the descendant view is unable to
        // scroll in the direction the user is scrolling, we dispatch once more but without skipping
        // our onInterceptTouchEvent. Note that RecyclerView automatically cancels active touches of
        // all its descendants once it starts scrolling so we don't have to do that.
        requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false)
        if (!handled || nestedScrollTargetWasUnableToScroll) {
            handled = super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev)
        }

        return handled
    }

    // We only support vertical scrolling.
    override fun onStartNestedScroll(child: View, target: View, nestedScrollAxes: Int) =
        nestedScrollAxes and ViewCompat.SCROLL_AXIS_VERTICAL != 0

    /*  Introduced with NestedScrollingParent2. */
    override fun onStartNestedScroll(child: View, target: View, axes: Int, type: Int) =
        onStartNestedScroll(child, target, axes)

    override fun onNestedScrollAccepted(child: View, target: View, axes: Int) {
        if (axes and View.SCROLL_AXIS_VERTICAL != 0) {
            // A descendant started scrolling, so we'll observe it.
            setTarget(target)
        }
        parentHelper.onNestedScrollAccepted(child, target, axes)
    }

    /*  Introduced with NestedScrollingParent2. */
    override fun onNestedScrollAccepted(child: View, target: View, axes: Int, type: Int) {
        if (axes and View.SCROLL_AXIS_VERTICAL != 0) {
            // A descendant started scrolling, so we'll observe it.
            setTarget(target)
        }
        parentHelper.onNestedScrollAccepted(child, target, axes, type)
    }

    override fun onNestedPreScroll(target: View, dx: Int, dy: Int, consumed: IntArray) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            dispatchNestedPreScroll(dx, dy, consumed, null)
        } else {
            super.onNestedPreScroll(target, dx, dy, consumed)
        }
    }

    /*  Introduced with NestedScrollingParent2. */
    override fun onNestedPreScroll(target: View, dx: Int, dy: Int, consumed: IntArray, type: Int) {
        onNestedPreScroll(target, dx, dy, consumed)
    }

    override fun onNestedScroll(
        target: View,
        dxConsumed: Int,
        dyConsumed: Int,
        dxUnconsumed: Int,
        dyUnconsumed: Int
    ) {
        if (target === nestedScrollTarget && dyUnconsumed != 0) {
            // The descendant could not fully consume the scroll. We remember that in order
            // to allow the RecyclerView to take over scrolling.
            nestedScrollTargetWasUnableToScroll = true
            // Let the parent start to consume scroll events.
            target.parent?.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false)
        }
    }

    /*  Introduced with NestedScrollingParent2. */
    override fun onNestedScroll(
        target: View,
        dxConsumed: Int,
        dyConsumed: Int,
        dxUnconsumed: Int,
        dyUnconsumed: Int,
        type: Int
    ) {
        onNestedScroll(target, dxConsumed, dyConsumed, dxUnconsumed, dyUnconsumed)
    }

    /*  Introduced with NestedScrollingParent3. */
    override fun onNestedScroll(
        target: View,
        dxConsumed: Int,
        dyConsumed: Int,
        dxUnconsumed: Int,
        dyUnconsumed: Int,
        type: Int,
        consumed: IntArray
    ) {
        onNestedScroll(target, dxConsumed, dyConsumed, dxUnconsumed, dyUnconsumed, type)
    }

    /* From ViewGroup */
    override fun onStopNestedScroll(child: View) {
        // The descendant finished scrolling. Clean up!
        setTarget(null)
        parentHelper.onStopNestedScroll(child)
    }

    /*  Introduced with NestedScrollingParent2. */
    override fun onStopNestedScroll(target: View, type: Int) {
        // The descendant finished scrolling. Clean up!
        setTarget(null)
        parentHelper.onStopNestedScroll(target, type)
    }

    /*  Introduced with NestedScrollingParent2. */
    override fun onNestedPreFling(target: View, velocityX: Float, velocityY: Float): Boolean {
        return if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            false
        } else {
            super.onNestedPreFling(target, velocityX, velocityY)
        }
    }

    /* In ViewGroup for API 21+. */
    override fun onNestedFling(
        target: View,
        velocityX: Float,
        velocityY: Float,
        consumed: Boolean
    ) =
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            false
        } else {
            super.onNestedFling(target, velocityX, velocityY, consumed)
        }

    private fun setTarget(target: View?) {
        nestedScrollTarget = target
        nestedScrollTargetWasUnableToScroll = false
    }
}
```

Now for the caveat: The preceding code has been *lightly (every so lightly)* tested. The *RecyclerView* environment is complex and the introduction of nested scrolling to *RecyclerView* as a parent of that scrolling makes it even more complex and prone to error. Nonetheless, it is an interesting study IMO.

Comment: Interesting approach, thanks.  Is the outer `RecyclerView` actually a `RecyclerView` or is it now a `ScrollView`?  I'm particularly attracted to using a `RecyclerView` as it can be associated with a `RecyclerView.Adapter` which implements a `Filterable`.

Comment: @drmrbrewer The outer view is a NestedRecyclerView as shown in the answer. The inner scrollable portion is just a vanilla RecyclerView. So it is a true nesting of RecyclerViews.

Comment: @drmrbrewer You should be able to replace your outer RecyclerView with a NestedRecyclerView to see the scrolling behave. I would be interested to know if that is not the case.

Comment: For the most part, this works really well. The only time I've run into an issue is if there's an `ItemTouchHelper` attached. In that case, a fling on the nested view is interpreted as a long-press on the item.

Comment: After a bit more playing around, I found a workaround by disabling the touch helper if the return value of `super.onNestedFling()` in the RecyclerView is false, as well as in `onNestedScroll()` if the delta is greater than the touch slop. It's not great, since it relies on setting a variable directly on the RecyclerView, but I'm not sure how else to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an extension to Zain's sample that avoids any custom scroll logic and chooses a combination of `NestedScrollView` & `RecyclerView`

[Github Link](https://github.com/rahul-a/VerticalNestedRecyclerView)

The key difference in approach here is to let the `NestedScrollView` handle the complex scroll computation around when to intercept/dispatch scroll events to the nested layouts.

I've added a `LinearLayout` container for the nested recyclers with a weight of 1 so they get the uniform height.

fwiw, we can also share view pools across recycler views for a better performance using `RecyclerView.setRecycledViewPool()`

PS: A definite hit on performance with this solution is that there will be `m * n` views loaded upon setup where: m - number of rows, n - visible views for the inner recycler.

Hence, for a large value of m, this won't scale very well.

Answer (score 0):

> Check this [Github Sample:](https://github.com/SimformSolutionsPvtLtd/SSExpandableRecylerView)

[image]

1. Extend BaseRecyclerAdapter(which you get whole code in github) in recycler adapter and implement below methods.

   ```
   class ListAdapter : BaseRecyclerAdapter<ListDataModel, ChildDataModel>() {

       // Pass parent and child model in BaseRecyclerAdapter

       override fun getLayoutIdForType(): Int = R.layout.item_parent  // Provide parent recycler item id

       override fun getLayoutIdForChild(): Int = R.layout.item_child  // Provide child recycler item id

       // Click event fot parent recycler item
       override fun onParentItemClick(triple: Triple<Int, Any, View>, viewDataBinding: ViewDataBinding) {
           val data = triple.second as ListDataModel // Here you can get parent item data for clicked item
           val position = triple.first // Get position of clicked item
           val view = triple.third // Get view of clicked item

           when (view.id) {
               R.id.text_movie_year -> {
                   // Call this function where you want to expand collapse childView
                   expandCollapse(triple.first, viewDataBinding)
               }
           }
       }

       // Click event for child rectycler item
       override fun onChildItemClicked(triple: Triple<Int, Any, View>, parentIndex: Int) {
       val data = triple.second as ChildDataModel // Here you can get child item data for clicked item
       val position = triple.first // Get position of clicked item
       val view = triple.third // Get view of clicked item

           when (view.id) {
               R.id.img_download_movie -> {
                   // Here you can perform your action
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

[Cheticamp's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68200773/vertical-recyclerview-nested-inside-vertical-recyclerview/68318211#68318211) works really well for cases where you don't need an `ItemTouchHelper` that supports dragging.

For that case, I came up with a messy but functional workaround:

```
class NestedRecyclerView @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : RecyclerView(context, attrs, defStyleAttr), NestedScrollingParent3 {
    private var nestedScrollTarget: View? = null
    private var nestedScrollTargetWasUnableToScroll = false
    private val parentHelper by lazy { NestedScrollingParentHelper(this) }

    /**
     * Set this wherever you have access to your item touch helper instance.
     * Using `attachToRecyclerView(null)` resets any long-press timers.
     *
     * Example:
     *
     * nestedRecyclerView.nestedScrollingListener = {
     *      itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(if (!it) nestedRecyclerView else null)
     * }
     */
    var nestedScrollingListener: ((Boolean) -> Unit)? = null

    /**
     * Set this from your item touch helper callback to let the RecyclerView
     * know when an item is selected (prevents an inverse nested scrolling issue
     * where the nested view scrolls and the item touch helper doesn't receive
     * further callbacks).
     *
     * Example:
     * override fun onSelectedChanged(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder?, actionState: Int) {
     *      if (actionState != ItemTouchHelper.ACTION_STATE_IDLE) nestedRecyclerView.selectedItem = true
     *      ...
     * }
     * ...
     * override fun clearView(recyclerView: RecyclerView, viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder) {
     *      nestedRecyclerView.selectedItem = false
     *      ...
     * }
     */
    var selectedItem: Boolean = false

    override fun dispatchTouchEvent(ev: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        // Nothing special if no child scrolling target.
        if (nestedScrollTarget == null || selectedItem) return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev)

        // Inhibit the execution of our onInterceptTouchEvent for now...
        requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true)
        // ... but do all other processing.
        var handled = super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev)

        // If the first dispatch yielded an unhandled event or the descendant view is unable to
        // scroll in the direction the user is scrolling, we dispatch once more but without skipping
        // our onInterceptTouchEvent. Note that RecyclerView automatically cancels active touches of
        // all its descendants once it starts scrolling so we don't have to do that.
        requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false)
        if (ev.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            // This is to prevent an issue where the item touch helper receives
            // an ACTION_DOWN but then doesn't later get the ACTION_UP event,
            // causing it to run any long-press events.
            nestedScrollingListener?.invoke(true)
            nestedScrollingListener?.invoke(false)
        }
        if (!handled || nestedScrollTargetWasUnableToScroll) {
            handled = super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev)
        }

        return handled
    }

    override fun getNestedScrollAxes(): Int {
        return parentHelper.nestedScrollAxes
    }

    // We only support vertical scrolling.
    override fun onStartNestedScroll(child: View, target: View, nestedScrollAxes: Int) =
        nestedScrollAxes and ViewCompat.SCROLL_AXIS_VERTICAL != 0

    /*  Introduced with NestedScrollingParent2. */
    override fun onStartNestedScroll(child: View, target: View, axes: Int, type: Int) =
        onStartNestedScroll(child, target, axes)

    override fun onNestedScrollAccepted(child: View, target: View, axes: Int) {
        if (axes and View.SCROLL_AXIS_VERTICAL != 0) {
            // A descendant started scrolling, so we'll observe it.
            setTarget(target)
        }
        parentHelper.onNestedScrollAccepted(child, target, axes)
    }

    /*  Introduced with NestedScrollingParent2. */
    override fun onNestedScrollAccepted(child: View, target: View, axes: Int, type: Int) {
        if (axes and View.SCROLL_AXIS_VERTICAL != 0) {
            // A descendant started scrolling, so we'll observe it.
            setTarget(target)
        }
        parentHelper.onNestedScrollAccepted(child, target, axes, type)
    }

    override fun onNestedPreScroll(target: View, dx: Int, dy: Int, consumed: IntArray) {
        super.onNestedPreScroll(target, dx, dy, consumed)
    }

    /*  Introduced with NestedScrollingParent2. */
    override fun onNestedPreScroll(target: View, dx: Int, dy: Int, consumed: IntArray, type: Int) {
        onNestedPreScroll(target, dx, dy, consumed)
    }

    override fun onNestedScroll(
        target: View,
        dxConsumed: Int,
        dyConsumed: Int,
        dxUnconsumed: Int,
        dyUnconsumed: Int
    ) {
        if (target === nestedScrollTarget && dyUnconsumed != 0) {
            // The descendant could not fully consume the scroll. We remember that in order
            // to allow the RecyclerView to take over scrolling.
            nestedScrollTargetWasUnableToScroll = true
            // Let the parent start to consume scroll events.
            target.parent?.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false)
        }
    }

    /*  Introduced with NestedScrollingParent2. */
    override fun onNestedScroll(
        target: View,
        dxConsumed: Int,
        dyConsumed: Int,
        dxUnconsumed: Int,
        dyUnconsumed: Int,
        type: Int
    ) {
        onNestedScroll(target, dxConsumed, dyConsumed, dxUnconsumed, dyUnconsumed)
    }

    /*  Introduced with NestedScrollingParent3. */
    override fun onNestedScroll(
        target: View,
        dxConsumed: Int,
        dyConsumed: Int,
        dxUnconsumed: Int,
        dyUnconsumed: Int,
        type: Int,
        consumed: IntArray
    ) {
        onNestedScroll(target, dxConsumed, dyConsumed, dxUnconsumed, dyUnconsumed, type)
    }

    /* From ViewGroup */
    override fun onStopNestedScroll(child: View) {
        // The descendant finished scrolling. Clean up!
        setTarget(null)
        parentHelper.onStopNestedScroll(child)
    }

    /*  Introduced with NestedScrollingParent2. */
    override fun onStopNestedScroll(target: View, type: Int) {
        // The descendant finished scrolling. Clean up!
        setTarget(null)
        parentHelper.onStopNestedScroll(target, type)
    }

    /*  Introduced with NestedScrollingParent2. */
    override fun onNestedPreFling(target: View, velocityX: Float, velocityY: Float): Boolean {
        return super.onNestedPreFling(target, velocityX, velocityY)
    }

    /* In ViewGroup for API 21+. */
    override fun onNestedFling(
        target: View,
        velocityX: Float,
        velocityY: Float,
        consumed: Boolean
    ) = super.onNestedFling(target, velocityX, velocityY, consumed).also {
        // If the nested fling wasn't consumed, then the touch helper can act.
        // Otherwise, disable it.
        nestedScrollingListener?.invoke(!it)
    }

    private fun setTarget(target: View?) {
        if (target == null) {
            // We're not nested scrolling anymore so the touch helper can
            // do its thing again.
            nestedScrollingListener?.invoke(false)
        }
        nestedScrollTarget = target
        nestedScrollTargetWasUnableToScroll = false

        // My specific implementation has nested ListViews (AppWidgetHost), so this is
        // also needed. If you have scrollable Views in general, you may need to use
        // View#setOnScrollChangeListener and check if the scroll change is non-zero.
        (target as? ListView)?.setOnScrollListener(object : AbsListView.OnScrollListener {
            override fun onScrollStateChanged(view: AbsListView?, scrollState: Int) {
                nestedScrollingListener?.invoke(scrollState != AbsListView.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE)
            }

            override fun onScroll(
                view: AbsListView?,
                firstVisibleItem: Int,
                visibleItemCount: Int,
                totalItemCount: Int
            ) {
            }
        })
    }
}
```

You need direct access to the `NestedRecyclerView` instance where you have your `ItemTouchHelper` and its callback in order to listen for and set different states. I've commented the new properties I added.